# Using Sum function in formula to add different data types

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make Cell (32,1) have a formula that sums a range of cells including integers and dates (example below). However, I am getting a Type Mismatch runtime error. How do I fix the formula line?
EDIT: Tried urdearboy's solution but the cell is now evaluating to a #NAME? error on the Excel Sheet. The displayed formula is: =SUM('A30':'A31') . Once I remove the apostrophes the issue goes away. How can I manipulate the VBA code so it doesn't print the apostrophes?

```
Range(Cells(30, 1), Cells(30, 1)).Value = DateValue("Jan 19, 2020")
Range(Cells(31, 1), Cells(31, 1)).Value = 10
Range(Cells(32, 1), Cells(32, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(30, 1), Cells(31, 1)) & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the address

---

```
Range("A30").Value = DateValue("Jan 19, 2020")
Range("A31").Value = 10

Range("A32").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range("A30:A31").Address(False, False) & ")"
```

Comment: Unclear why you are using `Range(Cells, Cells)` for one value so swapped that here. The same logic would apply if you reverted back to your format though

Comment: Tried that but the cell is now evaluating to a #NAME? error on the Excel Sheet. The displayed formula is: =SUM('A30':'A31') . Once I remove the apostrophes the issue goes away. How can I manipulate the VBA code so it doesn't print the apostrophes?

Comment: I tested this and it worked on my machine. I can’t reproduce the reported issue

Comment: The issue comes up when I try it added the address portion to Range(Cells(30, 1), Cells(31, 1)). Were you able to try that?

Comment: Why are you using that method? Are you swapping them for variables?

Comment: Per my first comment that’s not necessary here

Comment: Yes, I am swapping in variables. This was a simplified version